# Pandas: speed up iterating throught two dataframes

Tags: pandas, performance, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a DataFrame B, which has columns: `id_number, performance, min_value, max_value`.

```
B
id_number | perfomance | min_value | max_value
12        | A          | 400       | 700
4         | B          | 1000      |1250
89        | C          |1          | 30
```

I want to create a dictionary, in the following way:

```
for idx, r in B.iterrows():
  for i in range(r['min_value'], r['max_value'] + 1):
      dic[i] = r[id_number]
```

(Note, that id_number is not unique.)

My data frame B is very large (> 5M records), and very often the range between min and max is very large (thousands), so the whole process takes ages. Is there a way to implement faster the above dictionary creation?

Comment: the ranges [minvalue, maxvalue] are all unique?

Comment: Yes, indeed they are all unique

Comment: What is the purpose of the dict you are creating and how will you use it? I am asking because I think it might be very hard to optimize the code you already have and create the same dict, but it might be possible to find a way were you do not need the dict at all in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic = (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['id_number'], 
                                    index = np.arange(x['min_value'], x['max_value']+1)),
                axis=1)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .to_dict())
```